# POST Method on PHP does not work sometimes and send field empty

Tags: php, post

my PHP form short code is :

```
<form action="register.process.php" method="post">
<label for="code">Type</label><br/><select name="type"  style="width:265px;">
  <option value="ex" selected="selected">Exchange</option>
  <option value="computer">Computer</option>
  <option value="metal">Metal</option>
</select>
<label>Address</label><br/><input type="text" name="adr" />
<label>Phone</label><br/><input type="text" name="phn" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" style="width:265px; height:30px;"/>
</form>
```

and my register.process.php is :

```
<?php
$type = $_POST['type'];
$adr = $_POST['adr'];
$phn = $_POST['phn'];
$subject = "new data : ".$type." | ".$phn;
if($type =="" || $phn="" || $$adr=""){
    header( "refresh:1;url=store.register.php?error=1");
    $write = 1;
}
if($write != 1){
$msg = '<p>Type : '.$type."<br/>Address : ".$adr."<br/>Phone : ".$phn."</p>";
$to = "register@xcodz.com";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: xCodz Store Register <no-reply@xcodz.com>" . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers);
echo 'Your data has been sent!';
}
?>
```

i put that if condition for empty or null data, but empty fields are still passing this condition!
there is no different to sending this data to mail or save them in MySql.
usually ADR and PHN field are empty, or sometime just one of them is empty , but in 80% times this code works correct !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would never have worked anyways:

```
if($type =="" || $phn="" || $$adr=""){
                     ^--         ^---
```

You're doing assignments to the two indicated variables, not equality comparisons. Try `==` instead...

As well, you've got multiple typos in the rest of the code, as the color highlighting here indicates. Note how your `mail()` command is in red, meaning it's being interpreted as a string. You've got one or more unmatched quotes above.

Comment: thank you for reply, i made a mistake when i put my code here for asking question and i changed ' to " for one field, that red color for my mail() was for that, but i had blunder and big mistake for = ! i fix that, thank you,